# If No File, Rewrite URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two .htaccess files that I need to combine into one.

The first one does a simple file extension remover.

The second one rewrites all requests to go to a third party app, keeping our URL.

What I need is to have the rules be smart enough to not look at the second server if the file exists on the first.

Rule1 :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Rule 2:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://third.party.com/$1 [P]
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}([^?\ ]+) 
# RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/%1
```

I'm far from an .htaccess wizard, so I'm all ears for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the L flag to stop rewriting at a given rule. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://third.party.com/$1 [P]
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}([^?\ ]+) 
# RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/%1
```

See [the mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) (search for "Stop the rewriting process").

Answer (score 0):

So do you want one rule to work for one site and another one for the other? If yes, you can use RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} directives to limit their scope.